xmake setup for a simple app with lua scripting
I am trying to build a simple xmake based app, with the usual lua scripting, but how to write an xmake.lua for this still eludes me. For now I have this:
add_rules("mode.debug", "mode.release")
add_requires("lua")

target("Elevated")
    set_kind("binary")
    add_packages("lua")
    add_files("src/*.c")

and in my /src I have main.c file while .lua scripts are in, let's say /engine dir. Build succeeds with this main.c:
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaL_dofile(L, "engine/main.lua");
    return 0;
}

but I am amiss at how to move .lua scripts dir using xmake.lua. Obviously, I can copy it manually to the same dir where the built executable is, but I'm curious is there anything in xmake to automate this.

you can use set_rundir to set lua script directory, then use xmake run to run it.
target("Elevated")
    set_kind("binary")
    add_packages("lua")
    add_files("src/*.c")
    set_rundir("scripts")

then put your lua scripts to scripts directory. scripts/engine/main.lua
run your program.
xmake run

If you want to distribute your program, you can use add_installfiles, set_installdir to configure all installed lua script files. then run xmake install -o outputdir

Great, these were exactly the commands I needed. Thank you. I'm still surprised that lua-based xmake does not have this type of project in its examples.
